# Getting unique top value from array

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my Object array:

```
$prob[] = (object) array(
                        "value" => ($pos_Count + 1)/ ($totalPOS_count + $distinct_pos_Count),
                        "tag"   => $row1['tag'],
                        );
```

Here I am sorting and echoing top 5(by value) array values

```
    uasort ($prob, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a->value == $b->value) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a->value < $b->value) ? 1 : -1;
    });

    $prob = array_slice($prob, 0, 5);
    foreach ($prob as $array)
    {
        echo "Tag :". $array->tag." Probablity :".$array->value."<br/>";
    }
```

If array has repeating values like this:

```
Tag :Feedback Probablity :0.0085561497326203
Tag :Design Probablity :0.007177033492823
Tag :Design Probablity :0.007177033492823
Tag :services Probablity :0.006295907660021
Tag :services Probablity :0.006295907660021
```

It should print distinct `tags` with their value. Rather printing same tag twice as it is doing here for `Design` and `Services`.

this is correct:

```
Tag :articles Probablity :0.0022321428571429
Tag :Fun Probablity :0.0012771392081737
Tag :Facebook Probablity :0.0012771392081737
Tag :delivery Probablity :0.0012771392081737
Tag :Supplier Probablity :0.0012771392081737
```

So how can I echo only distinct top 5 tags here/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will replace the array_slice to get only the unique tags :

```
$prob[] = (object) array("value" => "DISPLAY ME", "tag" => 1,);
$prob[] = (object) array("value" => "DO NOT DISPLAY ME","tag" => 1,);
$prob[] = (object) array("value" => "DISPLAY ME","tag"   => 2,);
$new_prob = array();
$count = 0;
foreach ($prob as $array) {
    if (!array_key_exists($array->tag, $new_prob)) {
        $new_prob[$array->tag] = $array->value;
        if (++$count == 5) { // Number of unique elements to keep
            break;
        }
    }
}

foreach ($new_prob as $key => $value) {
    echo "Tag :". $key." Probablity :".$value."<br/>";
}
```

Result :

```
Tag :1 Probablity :DISPLAY ME
Tag :2 Probablity :DISPLAY ME
```